# nodeIntegrationInWorker enabled breaks monaco-editor loading in electron

Tags: electron, monaco-editor

You can reproduce the issue by enabling the `nodeIntegrationInWorker` in the webpack example in the samples - https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/electron-esm-webpack/main.js#L11

This is not an issue in previous versions of monaco-editor and only started with the update to typescript v5, from what I could debug. My very basic understanding pin points the issue to the change of detecting a node environment here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/dc92488da8de8ca204000ff5019f4c35915a5e37

Any ideas on how to workaround this? If I disabled the `nodeIntegrationInWorker` it works as expected but I unfortunately need it for another worker that requires node access.

Comment: As this seems like a bug and (maybe?) wasn't intentional since it's doing something very opposite here, I suggest to file a bug report with the Monaco project.